# Counting the number of students in a class

Tags: probability-theory

Out of a total of 40 students, 14 are taking English and 29 are taking Chemistry. Five students are in both classes. What is the probability that a randomly chosen student from this group of 40 students is: (i) In at least one of the classes? (ii) Taking only one class, i.e. Chemistry OR English?

**My attempt**:

- Five students are in both classes (given)
- Number of students taking English only = 14 - 5 = 9
- Number of students taking Chemistry only = 29 - 5 = 24
- Number of students in neither class = 40 - 38 = 2

So for (ii) we have (9 + 5 + 24)/40 = 0.95. I don't know how to do (i). Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your bullet points are all correct.

For (ii), you are correct if you mean Chemistry OR English. However, in mathematics OR is inclusive (think 'and/or'), but the wording 'taking only one class' means you shouldn't include the 5 taking both Chemistry and English. So you should end up with $$ P(1 \text{ class only}) = \frac{9 + 24}{40} = \frac{33}{40} = 0.85$$

For (i), 'at least one' means 'more than zero'. So this time you really do want $P(\text{Chemistry OR English})$, and so the answer is 0.95 by the calculation you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood your own results. You are correct that exactly $24$ students are taking Chemistry only and $9$ students are taking English only. So the number of students taking at least one is $24+9+5=38$. So $38/40 = 0.95$ is the answer to part (i).

For part (ii) the number of students taking exactly one class is $24+9=33$. So $33/40 = 0.825$ is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that the **keyword** *at least one* is equal to *one classes + two classes*. In this type of exercise is better work with the complement.

So, the probababilty of $i) P(x) = 1 - P(x)^c$, where $P(x)^c$ is the complement of *at least one*  that is *have zero classes*. Thus, the students that have zero classes are $2/40$, then substract from $1 => 40/40 - 2/40 = 38/40$

With $ii)$ You don't have to add $5$ because these five students have two classes. So the correct answer is $9/40 + 24/40 = 33/40$